# Logging just length in console returns 1

Tags: javascript

I logged (length) in console and it returned 1. Generally javascript compiler would throw an error like "length is not defined" but here it returned 1, is there any relevance of this default value of length ?

```
> console.log(length)

  Output: 1
```

Comment: it depends on the context this is run. i believe `window.length` is a thing - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/length

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`window.length` returns the number of frames

Read more about [Window.length on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/length)

> Returns the number of frames (either `<frame>` or `<iframe>` elements) in the window.

On a (blank) page without such elements it's expected to return `0`, here on this exact StackOverflow page you might expect something like `2`

To get more info you might want to use `window.frames`

Also from the MDN Docs [Window.frames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames):

> Window.frames
> Returns the window itself, which is an array-like object, listing the direct sub-frames of the current window.